# What is EXT JS's method to use "display:none"

Tags: hide, visibility, show-hide, extjs

Hello I have to load an ajax element into div. That div would earlier have another sub div by the name div1, and to remove/hide the div1, I am doing a Ext.get('div1').hide(). But this is doing a `visibility:hidden`, rather than doing a `display:none`.

I wanted to know what is the method to do a `display:none` rather than a `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to change the visibility mode to display.

```
var element = Ext.get('div1');
element.setVisibilityMode(Ext.Element.DISPLAY);
element.hide();
```

Comment: That worked well Robby, I need to load another div into my main div. It is very similar to the load method in JQuery, can you tell me how do I go about with that?

Comment: @macha, you should mark this answer correct and create a new question for your load scenario.