# How to make element not printable in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, printing, show-hide

The element is something like:

```
items.push({
        xtype: 'panel',
        key: 'key',
        layout: 'table',
        cls: 'spaced-bottom-shallow',
        defaultType: 'label',
        hidden: false
})
```

I hide the element from display by setting property

```
hidden = false;
```

But element is still exist in print form (Cntl + P) in browser.
It seems I need to completele remove/not-display this element no to print it (not sure how).
Is there any other way to make element not-printable except removing element?
I use ExtJs and Chrome.

Comment: hidden = false; to hide the element? hidden = true; to hide it

Comment: The solution described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407827/what-is-ext-jss-method-to-use-displaynone
solved my problem.